# DATEDIFF Subquery returns more than 1 row in mysql

Tags: mysql

Having an issue with a specific section of a query using `DATEDIFF`:

```
select 1 as NumApps, 
LenderInfo.Name as LenderName,
CASE WHEN ApplicationInfo.AEType IS NULL OR ApplicationInfo.AEType = 0 THEN 'Unknown' ELSECONCAT    (AEContact.FirstName, ' ', AEContact.LastName) END As AEName,
CASE WHEN b.createdby > 0 THEN CONCAT (contactinfo.firstname, ' ', contactinfo.lastname) END AS LogActionBy,
CASE WHEN ApplicationInfo.RecertificationById IS NULL THEN CASE WHEN ApplicationInfo.IsCorrespondent IS NULL OR ApplicationInfo.IsCorrespondent = 0 THEN 'Wholesale' ELSE 'Correspondent' END ELSE CASE WHEN ApplicationInfo.IsCorrespondent IS NULL OR ApplicationInfo.IsCorrespondent = 0 THEN 'Wholesale - Recert' ELSE 'Correspondent- Recert' END END As AppType,
Applicationinfo.SubmissionDate,
ApplicationInfo.ApplicationID,
b.status AS LogStatus,
b.CreatedOn as LogDate,
companyinfo.Name,
companyinfo.NMLSEntityID,
applicationinfo.CreatedDate,        
ApplicationInfo.Status as ApplicationStatus,
ApplicationInfo.StatusChangeDate,
DATEDIFF ((Select CreatedOn From ApplicationStatusChangeLog a where a.ApplicationId = b.ApplicationId
And a.status = 'Approved'),(Select CreatedOn From ApplicationStatusChangeLog a Where a.ApplicationId = b.ApplicationId And a.status = 'Pending Approval')) AS DaysToApprove
from applicationinfo 
INNER JOIN CompanyInfo ON(ApplicationInfo.CompanyId = CompanyInfo.CompanyId)
left join   CompanyInfo As LenderInfo ON (ApplicationInfo.LenderId = LenderInfo.CompanyId)
LEFT JOIN UserInfo ON (UserInfo.UserId = ApplicationInfo.LastModifiedById)
LEFT JOIN ContactInfo ON UserInfo.ContactId = ContactInfo.ContactId
LEFT JOIN ContactInfo AS Comergence ON(ApplicationInfo.ComergenceRepId = Comergence.ContactId)
LEFT JOIN UserInfo AS AEUser ON(AEUser.UserId = ApplicationInfo.AEType)
left join   paymentinfo on applicationinfo.applicationid = paymentinfo.applicationid
Inner join applicationstatuschangelog b on applicationinfo.applicationid = b.applicationid
LEFT JOIN ContactInfo AS AEContact ON(AEContact.ContactId = AEUser.ContactId)
LEFT JOIN UserInfo AS StatusUser ON(StatusUser.UserId = ApplicationInfo.StatusChangeById)
LEFT JOIN ContactInfo AS StatusContact ON(StatusContact.ContactId = StatusUser.ContactId)
LEFT JOIN ApprovalStatus ON(ApplicationInfo.ApplicationId = ApprovalStatus.ApplicationId AND ApplicationInfo.CompanyId = ApprovalStatus.CompanyHQId
AND ApplicationInfo.CompanyId = ApprovalStatus.CompanyId)
Where ApplicationInfo.Status NOT In ('Approved Monitor Only')
AND LenderInfo.ActiveLenderContract = 1
AND COALESCE(ApplicationInfo.IsDeleted,0) <> 1
AND b.Status NOT IN ('Incomplete', 'Not Submitted')
Group BY b.ApplicationID`
```

I've seen some people mentioning using `IN` instead of `=` within the subquery, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas out there? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the entire query.  My guess is that this select-within-a-select is not the best approach.

Comment: Edited to include entire query - thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: "Having an issue with" isn't much of a problem description. Please at least put some effort into providing a question here that people can answer. (Sample data, the output you expect, and the output you're getting instead, for instance, would go a long way toward making that wall of SQL understandable.)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the query working by adding 'Limit 1' after the identified status:

`(Select CreatedOn From ApplicationStatusChangeLog a where a.ApplicationId = b.ApplicationId
And a.status = 'Approved' LIMIT 1),(Select CreatedOn From ApplicationStatusChangeLog a Where a.ApplicationId = b.ApplicationId And a.status = 'Pending Approval' LIMIT 1)`